# TCP socket data consumption

Tags: sockets, tcp, tcpclient, consumption

I send data to my server from my TCP socket every 5 seconds. How much data would be consumed in an hour at this rate of sending messages.

Every time, a socket is opened and data is pumped out of it from the client to the sever. I am using a 3G GSM modem on my client side.

my message is, ID1$Socket$Open$timestamp. All are strings

Comment: Impossible to answer until you tell us how much data you send every 5 seconds.

Comment: @nos  my message is, ID1$Socket$Open$timestamp. All are strings

Answer (score 0):

`ID1$Socket$Open$timestamp` is 25 bytes, assuming an 8-bit string, and assuming you are not sending any other data (headers/delimiters, etc) in between your messages.

So, 1 message sent every 5 seconds is `60 / 5 = 12` messages per minute, which is `12 * 60 = 720` messages per hour.  At 25 bytes per message, that is `720 * 25 = 18000` bytes per hour (plus overhead for TCP/IP headers and framing per message, and ACKs per TCP frame).

Comment: Somewhere there is a paper that shows the maximum bandwidth utilization of TCP is either 83% or 87%, I forget which, the rest being headers and maybe ACKs.

Comment: TCP alone doesn't provide sufficient information to calculate such.  Now if you say TCP/IP over 10baseT, then you have a 1500 byte maximum MTU with minimum 20 byte TCP and IP headers so 1460 payload bytes.  Then ethernet adds a 14-byte header, a 4-byte CRC, 7-byte preamble, and 1-byte start-of-frame.  There is also a 12-byte inter-frame-gap.  Thus, assuming no breaks you have 1460/1538 == 94.9%.  ACKs take no additional space and bandwidth is usually bidirectional.  Other network technologies have different framing and different MTU thus changing the maximum efficiency.